# ASP.NET MVC: Connection Controller with Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, uiviewcontroller

I'm still learning, but with the stackoverflow commnuties help, I've been able to get closer and closer.

What I have right now is a View "Index.aspx":

```
System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Data.Models.GetDealsModel>
```

The Model:

```
public class GetDealsModel
    {
        // set up the model
        public string DealId { get; set; }
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string Logo { get; set; }
        public string Website { get; set; }

        public string TotalRows { get; set; }

    }
```

And the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            LinqToDealsDataContext db = new LinqToDealsDataContext();
            XElement xmlTree = XElement.Parse("<Request><ZipCode>92612</ZipCode></Request>");

            var deals = db.spSearchDeals(xmlTree);

            return View(deals);
        }
```

And with this configuration I'm now getting this error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider+SingleResult`1[Data.Models.spSearchDealsResult]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Data.Models.GetDealsModel'.
```

I'm guessing that there's an issue connecting my Controller to my Model... I'm not sure why. PLEASE help me connect this final peice.

NOTE: I do understand that eventually I should separate my logic in the controller into a Repository Pattern, but for now, this will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your learning curve list the following items:

1. Repository Pattern
2. Ask yourself the following question:  Why do I need a service layer?
3. Read Steven Sanderson's book.  It teaches you to think in MVC.

The above applies to your problems because your issues are clearly related to having code in your Controllers that should be in your Model (ie, data access code should be in a repository class).  Ie, you are not thinking in MVC.

**Your model should include the necessary repository classes, eg, DealRepository.**

**You need a Service class to map the objects your repository digs out of your database to your model class:  that way conversion problems are encapsulated into the Service Layer code.**

If you do this, you can then write in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return(DealService.GetByZipcode(92612));
        }
```

Where DealService.GetByZipcode basically just maps DealRepository.GetByZipcode(92612) to your model class and returns the mapping result.

The DealRepository.GetByZipcode method would be roughly:

```
public static DealEntity GetByZipcode(string zip)
{
            LinqToDealsDataContext db = new LinqToDealsDataContext();
            XElement xmlTree = XElement.Parse("<Request><ZipCode>" + zip + "</ZipCode></Request>");

            var deals = db.spSearchDeals(xmlTree);

            return deals;
        }
```

The DealEntity class is just whatever Linq gives you for your table.

### The reason WHY for all this:

The reason for this structure is as follows:

a.  All you data access code is in one place:  DealRepository.  You can test and debug that independently of everything else.

b.  The mapping code is all in one place:  DealService.  You can test and debug that independently of everything else.

c. In other words, you need to properly separate your concerns.

The problem with your existing code is precisely that you have NOT separated concerns.  Ie, you have taken a dash of MVC and put it in a food processor and ended up with mush full of problems that are way more difficult to deal with than they need be.

Your model is mixed into your controller, there is no repository, no service layer.

So hold your horses just a while and take the time to read Steve Sanderson's book.

I would also try modelling a simpler problem.  That xml parsing makes my head hurt even on a good day.

### NOTE:

You could seriously improve your naming conventions.  LinqToDealsDataContext?  You're kidding, right?

Answer (score 2):

You need to translate the data coming back from this call:

```
var deals = db.spSearchDeals(xmlTree);
```

into a `GetDealsModel` type.  So something like:

```
GetDealsModel dealsModel = new GetDealsModel()
{
   DealId = deals.DealId,
   StreetAddress = deals.StreetAddress,
....
};

return View(dealsModel);
```

The reason being that your View is strongly typed to take a `GetDealsModel`, but your `deals` variable is not of that type and it gives you that exception when you pass it to the View.

Comment: Man, this is so close... so I did this but when I assign DealId = deals.DealId, deals.DealId "does not contain definition"

Comment: One of my issues is that this call produces 2 result sets... so the first thing I need to know how to do is extract each result set. Any idea?

Comment: I might be able to if I could see the structure of what is coming back in that result set.

Comment: @amurra:  And where it is coming from...  Ie, what table(s).  What "shape" does this data have??  It's just not clear.

Comment: @awrigley - Right I agree. My code above is just an example of what needs to be done with the deals data. Without knowing how the data is structured that code won't work, but should give the general idea.

Comment: @amurra:  I was agreeing with you and adding to your comment for dcolombus' attention.

Comment: The return is two tables (two rows): first one is some tag information and the second is deal information. Nothing too fancy... I just can't get to the second resultset.

Answer (score 1):

You should create object of type GetDealsModel, but your DB Query returns object of type Data.Models.spSearchDealsResult. Try something like:

```
return new GetDealsModel
           {
              DealId = deals.Id,
              // other fields here
           }
```